# Gitlab CI is it possible to keep common lines in one file and refer it in other files

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
include:
    - local: file-1.gitlab-ci.yml
    - local: file-2.gitlab-ci.yml
```

file-1.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
some-script: &some-script
   .......

job1:
 script:
   - *some-script
```

file-2.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
some-script: &some-script
   .......

job2:
 script:
   - *some-script
```

Here `some-script`(shown in the example) is same in both files `file-1` and `file-2` but I have to maintain it in two places. It is possible to keep `some-script` in a common file say file-3 and use it from there in file-1 file-2, so that if there are changes, the changes only need to be done in file-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [!reference tag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) could solve your problem.

You could move the `some-script` part to its own `file-3` file.

```
.some-script:
  script:
    - ...
```

And then reference the `script` block from `file-3` in `file-1`/`file-2`.

```
include:
    - local: file-3.gitlab-ci.yml
job1:
 script:
   - !reference [.some-script, script]
```